# Grouping of blogdetails based on tagname is not happening

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to group `blogdetails` based on `tagname`. On click on second plus button, would like to group all the blog details under each tagname. At the moment, it is ignoring the grouping and just displaying tagname.
Could someone please advise what could be the issue here ?
I have added the code sandbox link for reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sound-dzpohx?file=/src/App.js

```js
// data structure
const detailsTag = [
  {
    id: 1,
    tagname: "react",
    blogdetails: "React State details" 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tagname: "unix",
    blogdetails: "Unix grep command" 
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    tagname: "cypress",
    blogdetails: "Cypress request command"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    tagname: "react",
    blogdetails: "Usage of Context in React" 
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    tagname: "unix",
    blogdetails: "Unix list command" 
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    tagname: "react",
    blogdetails: "How to use useMemo in react hooks" 
  },        
]
```

```js
// methods in React component
const [detailsTags, setDetailsTags] = useState(detailsTag);
const [filterTags, setFilterTags] = useState([]);

const tags = filterTags.reduce((tags, tag) => {
  if (!tags[tag.tagname]) tags[tag.tagname] = [];
  tags[tag.tagname].push(tag.tagname);
  return tags;
}, {});
```

```
// jsx    
<div className='groupbyTags'>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='plusBtn'>
      <input onClick={handleClick} style={style} type="button" value="+"> </input>
    </div>
    {isShown && (
      <div className='groupByTagData'>
      {
        groupTags.map(({ id, count, tagname }) => (
          <div key={id} className='row'>
            <div className='groupByTagInfo'>
              <input id="childBlogBtn" onClick={() => showFullDetails(id)} style={style} type="button" value="+"></input>
            </div>{" "} <br></br>
            {isShownFullDetails === id && (
              <div className='groupByTagRecord'>
                {
                  Object.entries(tags).map(([tagname, blogdetails]) => (
                    <div key={tagname} className="blogdata">
                      {blogdetails.map((data) => (
                        <span key={data} className="data-1">
                          {data.blogdetails}
                        </span>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  ))
                }
              </div>
            )}
            <div className="groupByTagInfo">
              <span className="groupByTagCount">{count}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="groupByTagInfo">
              <span className="groupByTagName">{tagname}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired grouping of blog details for each tag looks as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const blogdetailsForTag = (arr, search) => {
  return arr
    .filter((element) => element.tagname === search) // loop through arr and return each element that have a tagname equal to search
    .map((item) => item.blogdetails); // map through the returned array and return blogdetails for each item
}
```

So this function returns an array of strings (blogdetails) of the items of a given array which have the same given search value

### Implementation:

```js
const GroupByTags = () => {
  const [groupTags, setGroupTags] = useState(data);
  const [detailsTags, setDetailsTags] = useState(detailsTag);
  const [filterTags, setFilterTags] = useState([]);
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  const [isShownFullDetails, setShowFullDetails] = useState(false);

  const style = {
    width: "30px",
    height: "30px",
    marginLeft: "20px",
    backgroundColor: "#dae0f5",
    fontWeight: "900",
    opacity: 1,
    borderColor: "#fafcff",
  };

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setIsShown((current) => !current);
  };

  const showFullDetails = (idx) => {
    const filterdata = detailsTags.filter((item) => item?.id === idx);
    setShowFullDetails((prev) => (prev === idx ? false : idx));
    setFilterTags( // use the same logic to set filterTags
      detailsTags
        .filter((element) => element.tagname === filterdata[0].tagname)
        .map((item) => item.blogdetails)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <div className="groupbyTags">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="plusBtn">
            <input
              onClick={handleClick}
              style={style}
              type="button"
              value="+"
            ></input>
          </div>
          {isShown && (
            <div className="groupByTagData">
              {groupTags.map(({ id, count, tagname }) => (
                <div key={id} className="row">
                  <div className="groupByTagInfo">
                    <input
                      onClick={() => showFullDetails(id)}
                      style={style}
                      type="button"
                      value="+"
                    ></input>
                  </div>{" "}
                  <br></br>
                  {isShownFullDetails === id && (
                    <div className="groupByTagData">
                      {filterTags.map((blogdetails, index) => (
                        <div className="blogdata" key={index}>
                          <span className="data-1">{blogdetails}</span>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <div className="groupByTagInfo">
                    <span className="groupByTagCount">{count}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="groupByTagInfo">
                    <span className="groupByTagName">{tagname}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GroupByTags;
```

Comment: ..But when you iterate

Comment: is it like   `Object.entries(groupedItemps).map(({tagname, blogdetails}) => (
                                                    <div key={tagname} className="team-1">
                                                      {blogdetails.map((tagname) => (
                                                        <span key={tagname} className="data-1">
                                                          {tagname}`

Comment: you want to return an array of `blogdetails` based on a give tag ?

Comment: Yes. I want return array of `blogdetails` based on a given grouped  tag

Comment: Sorry it is throwing some exception

Comment: isn't [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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) what you want ?

Comment: I updated my answer with the full component code