# why the state doesn't change in this case when using useState

Tags: reactjs

i'm a rookie in react

the code is:

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
  const add = () => {
    console.log(current)
    setCurrent(current + 1)
  }
  const Parent = (props) => {
    return props.data.child
  }
  const Child = () => {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => {
        add()
      }}>Child</div>
    )
  }    
  // const data = {
  //   child: <Child></Child>
  // }
  const [data] = useState({
    child: <Child></Child>
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <Parent data={data}>
      </Parent>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now the console out is 0 on every click, but when not using useState, the current will increace

I don't know why, could any one explain for me, thank you so so much

Comment: Don’t put React components in state. The Child component in your state has a stale closure over the initial add function, so it won’t update properly. Research JavaScript closures, which will take a while to learn, then read about React state and rendering. Only store data in state, not React elements.

Comment: @AndyRay thank you, the reason why i put components in state is i want to change the antd component tree's icon props dynamically, how to do it properly, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`useState` only user for store data, not element. I see do you want to send data from Parent to Child. Try this!

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const add = () => {
    console.log(current);
    setCurrent(current + 1);
  };
  const Parent = ({ children }) => {
    return <>{children}</>;
  };
  const Child = () => {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          add();
        }}
      >
        Child
      </div>
    );
  };

  const [data] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <Parent data={data}>
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you, the reason why i put components in state is i want to change the antd component tree's icon props dynamically, how to do it properly, thanks again   [antd tree](https://ant.design/components/tree)

Comment: You can add icon on treeData.
Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/customize-icon-antd-5-3-1-forked-q29qtn?file=/demo.tsx:573-665

Comment: @DũngGramer If you have time, could you please help with this problem >>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75739304/grouping-of-blogdetails-based-on-tagname-is-not-happening

Answer (score 0):

I get it
if use

```
const data = {
  child: <Child></Child>
}
```

Child is new, the `current` in add function closure is new on every render.

but if use

```
const [data] = useState({
  child: <Child></Child>
})
```

Child is the same one in 2nd render, the `current` in add function closure is the same one, not the new `current` in 2nd render process.